# Ruby cannot see NLS_LANG environmental variable

Tags: ruby, bash, oci8

I'm running a ruby script on CentOS, and installed ruby via rvm (1.9.3).

I've set the NLS_LANG variable in .bash_profile.

```
[app@box stasis]$ echo $NLS_LANG
en_US.UTF-8
[app@box stasis]$ which ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
```

However when trying to access it via ruby (which the oci8 driver does), it cannot find it:

```
 1.9.3-p194 :001 > ENV['NLS_LANG']
 => nil
```

Accessing other vars seems to work:

```
 1.9.3-p194 :004 > ENV['USER']
 => "app"
```

My script shows the following: `Warning: NLS_LANG is not set. fallback to US7ASCII.`

Thing is I'm running sqlplus from the ruby script (to execute some .sql files), and special characters are all messed up.

How can I get ruby to see the value?

Comment: Does `NLS_LANG` show up when you run `env` in the shell?

Comment: It was not showing up. I was setting the variable in .bash_profile, but not exporting it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to export your variables to be available in any applications run (unless they are functions):

```
export NLS_LANG
```

or together with setting:

```
export NLS_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

or as on most systems `LANG` should be available:

```
export NLS_LANG=$LANG
```

Comment: Does LANG really contain the format that Oracle expects in NLS_LANG?

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I wasn't exporting the variable. 'en_US.UTF-8' did not work though (oci8 said it was invalid). I used `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8` and oci8 did not complaint about it.

Comment: So this is ancient, but please remember that UTF8 is not UTF8 in Oracle. You need to use AL32UTF8. http://wonderingmisha.blogspot.jp/2011/10/utf8-vs-al32utf8.html